# Symfony map inherited properties in ORM storage class

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, payum

I extend a class which defines some properties.

I have to make the inherited properties be stored in my database to map the resulting entity.

How would the syntax for this look like?

I extend the Payum Payment Model Class "PaymentDetails" which itself is extending the class "Payment" shown below:

```
/**
 * Class Payment
 *
 * Lets you create, process and manage payments.
 *
 * @package PayPal\Api
 *
 * @property string id
 * @property string intent
 * @property \PayPal\Api\Payer payer
 * @property \PayPal\Api\Transaction[] transactions
 * @property string state
 * @property string experience_profile_id
 * @property string note_to_payer
 * @property \PayPal\Api\Payee $payee
 * @property \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls redirect_urls
 * @property string failure_reason
 * @property string create_time
 * @property string update_time
 * @property \PayPal\Api\Links[] links
 */
class Payment extends PayPalResourceModel
{
    // ...
}
```

The class "PaymentDetails" is:

```
use PayPal\Api\Payment as BasePaymentDetails;

class PaymentDetails extends BasePaymentDetails
{
    protected $idStorage;
}
```

My own class looks like this atm:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PaymentPaypalPlus extends PaymentDetails
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="idPpp", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @var integer $idPpp;
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

I somehow need to make the class "PaymentPaypalPlus" work as a valid storage class for Payum which means I have to map the properties from the base classes to DB (using ORM). At least that's what I think I should do. If this doesn't make sense please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

It think the closest thing that you are looking for is something like [php-mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/php-mapping.html) or [yaml-mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html).

If the properties are protected you could also redefine them in a subclass with annotations - this would however kind of defeat the purpose of inheritance unless there are many functions/etc as well that can stay as they are.

Actual inheritance like [doctrine inheritance-mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) or even [PHP Traits](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.traits.php) work as well, but you would have to modify your vendor class.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. I am trying to go for php-mapping way. However - normally I call `doctrine:schema:update --force` to update my DB structure. How would I do this when I use the `StaticPHPDriver`? Can you say anything about the approach itself? Does this make any sense at all to map this properties to use the base class as a storage class? Or is the intended reason for the base classes existence something else? @Jenne van der Meer